# Filter over Nested Map value's in Spring data mongo query-dsl

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, querydsl

I am integrating the Spring-Data-mongo with query-dsl, so i need to Generate Q-files for query-dsl queries 
Here is my Order POJO:

```
public class Order {
    private List<Map<String,Object>> items;
}
```

My Q file of Order.java

```
public class QOrder extends EntityPathBase<Order> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -682690651L;

    public static final QOrder order = new QOrder("order");

    public final ListPath<java.util.Map<String, Object>, SimplePath<java.util.Map<String, Object>>> items = this.<java.util.Map<String, Object>, SimplePath<java.util.Map<String, Object>>>createList("items", java.util.Map.class, SimplePath.class, PathInits.DIRECT2);

    public QOrder(String variable) {
        super(Order.class, forVariable(variable));
    }

    public QOrder(Path<? extends Order> path) {
        super(path.getType(), path.getMetadata());
    }

    public QOrder(PathMetadata metadata) {
        super(Order.class, metadata);
    }
}
```

and sample json's of order is

```
{
    "items": [{
        "itemName": "phone",
        "quantity": <Integer-Number>
    }
    ]
}
```

Now  i want to retrieve all the order's from mongo for which any Item exist with qunatity 1.
Now i am generating my predicate like below.
"QSensorData.sensorData.data.any().eq(**Some-QueryDSL-Expression**)".

I am unable to identify what need to pass in eq method for filtering nested map values.

Comment: As I understand Query dsl to query domain type using type safe api. So using `Map` data type to query is not the right way as you can just use the mongo java driver directly using `Document`.  So if you could update Order pojo to include all fields and then you can generate Q classes and use type safe way to query mongodb.

Comment: @veeram I have provided my Q classes that was generated by querydsl plugin above please check and let me know is there something wrong with that

Comment: The choice of data type Map is not correct. Can you change the Order pojo to include fields like item name, quantity etc instead of List<Map> ? What is expected output ? Are you looking to filter items based on quantity ? If yes then you can’t use dsl query as it requires aggregation query.

Answer (score 4):

Change Order class to include List attribute where Item contains itemName and quantity fields. Something like

```
public class Order {
    private List<Item> items;
}

public class Item {
    private String itemName;
    private Integer quantity;
}
```

Generate Q classes.

Use below query to return all items where there is atleast one item with quantity with 1.

```
BooleanExpression expression = QOrder.order.items.any().quantity.eq(1);
List<Order> results = repository.findAll(expression);
```

As noted in the comment to return all filtered items with value 1 you have to use aggregation query.

Something like

Static Imports

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ArrayOperators.Filter.filter;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ComparisonOperators.Eq.valueOf;
```

Aggregation Query

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
           project().and(filter("items")
             .as("item")
             .by(valueOf(
                  "item.quantity")
                   .equalToValue(
                  1)))
          .as("items");
);

List<Order> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, Order.class, Order.class)
```

Comment: If using pojo keys will be constrained so i was trying to avoid that.

Comment: Sorry it is not possible to query the map directly using query dsl. Query dsl provides type safe queries which requires keys. You can use mongo java driver directly if you just like to use Map.

Comment: Please provide comment when downvoting